# How to get user ID from post link in social network?

Tags: php, regex, facebook, social-networking

For example: I have a link to FB post `https://www.facebook.com/user_id/posts/684028375603651`
Is there a way to get the part `https://www.facebook.com/user_id/` using PHP? Maybe simply cut 21 chars at the end? Does FB post always have 15-digits post ID?
Or maybe it's possible to grab the part after `https://www.facebook.com/` and before next `/`?

Need this also for Twitter, Instagram and Soundcloud post links. (website offers free ads for one post but only once for one account)

Comment: Whatever you are thinking, you should try yourself first and show your effort.

Comment: When I post question on stackowerflow it helps me to concentrate and find answer faster :-D this i found in google and tested, seems that it works `<?php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "https://www.facebook.com/user_id/posts/684028375603651";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "https://www.facebook.com/", "/");

echo $parsed; ?>`

Comment: This sounds like something that regex could solve, or maybe a combination of http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe?

```
if( preg_match('https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/(.*?)\/', $link, $matches) ) {

    $facebookLink = 'https://www.facebook.com/' . $matches[1] . '/'; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php to find the last occurrence of '/' in the URL, and then http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php to truncate just the ID from the end.

```
$fb = "https://www.facebook.com/user_id/posts/684028375603651";
$i = strrpos($fb, '/');
$id = substr($fb, $i+1);
```